# Filter between version names and version numbers

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

when I run the script kit_version.sh I get the following output

```
 #  ./kit_version.bash

  --- USAW Kits ---
  RPM Kits                               Installed Time
  ------------------------------------   ---------------------------------
 APP-IR-LRPS-1.1.0.0-01            Thu 15 Nov 2012 11:10:20 AM IST
 APP-V-LRPS-4.3.7.0-01             Mon 15 Oct 2012 04:27:54 PM IST
 batter-ic-4.3.0.0-04              Mon 24 Feb 2014 02:10:21 PM IST
 CSHRS-Monitoring-5.0.0.0-03       Mon 24 Feb 2014 03:32:43 PM IST
 CS-RH-watchdog-conf-5.0.0.0-03    Mon 24 Feb 2014 03:32:42 PM IST
 CSe-OSP-Bin-5.0.0.0-01            Mon 24 Feb 2014 03:28:00 PM IST
 sca_core_2.5.7.0-7                Sun 29 Mar 2015 02:36:46 PM IDT
 sca_data:80.7.0-7                 Sun 29 Mar 2015 02:37:04 PM IDT
 .
 .
 .
```

How to filter the output so I get in the first field only the package name and the second field 
only the version  number as the following:

```
 ./kit_version.bash | ......



APP-IR-LRPS             1.1.0.0-01            
APP-V-LRPS              4.3.7.0-01            
batter-ic               4.3.0.0-04               
CSHRS-Monitoring        5.0.0.0-03      
CS-RH-watchdog-conf         5.0.0.0-03   
CSe-OSP-Bin             5.0.0.0-01     
sca_core                2.5.7.0-7
sca_data                80.7.0-7
```

- Remark – the separator between the version name to version number could be different char

Comment: whish are your rules for separation ?  (ex for a line like `APP-IR1-2-LR1_2.02-PS-1.1.0.0-01`) Separation after first digit found or when only digit, dot and underscore are present (from the end of string name)

Comment: yes - this option chuld be , I mean version name chuld be with number/s , but the version number is pure number include the "." or "-" chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk, I can imagine

```
 ./kit_version.bash | gawk '{ print gensub(/.([0-9.]+-[0-9.]+)$/, "\t\\1", 1, $1) }'
```

This will replace the character before a string matching a version number at the end of the first field with a tab and print the result of that substitution. To cut off the first three lines, use

```
awk 'NR > 3 { print gensub(/.([0-9.]+-[0-9.]+)$/, "\t\\1", 1, $1) }'
```

that is, add the `NR > 3` condition.

Alternatively with sed:

```
./kit_version.bash | sed '1d;2d;3d;s/[[:space:]].*//;s/.\([0-9.]\+-[0-9.]\+\)$/\t\1/'
```

That is:

```
1d                              # first three lines: delete
2d
3d
s/[[:space:]].*//               # remove everything after the first space,
                                # i.e., everything except the first field
s/.\([0-9.]\+-[0-9.]\+\)$/\t\1/ # then substitute as before.
```

This depends on no packages ending with a number while also being delimited from the version number by a period. That is to say,

```
#            vvvvvvvv-- if this is supposed to be the version
somepackage2.3.4.5-10
```

will not work properly (it will give `somepackag 2.3.4.5-10`). It seems unlikely that this format is allowed, though.

Comment: yes its work , but what in case gawk not installed on my linux machine , can I use awk ?

Comment: add +1 for your answer

Comment: `gensub` is gawk-specific, so unfortunately not. I added a sed solution that works essentially the same way, though.

Comment: WOW sed is very cool here ( while sed defined on all linux version ) , so I think its the best solution

Comment: sample dont show delete line but empty lines ( not a problem for your script that will be easily adapted, but just specify this). For the sed: `1,3d` or `1,/^-----/d`

Comment: I noitce that the sed solution not works on that line "CCPlbl-4.0.1.0-5.0" ,

Comment: That's because of the extra dot after the `-`. Use `s/.\([0-9.]\+-[0-9.]\+\)$/\t\1/` to catch it. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
./kit_version.bash \
| sed 's/^[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/;T clean;s/[-._]\([0-9][0-9._-]*\)$/\t\1/;t;:clean;s/.*//'
```

- reformat the line (remove heading space and trialing info)
- if no modif, go to cleaning the line
- reformat to separate *version* from name

Only with GNU sed due to `T` option (or need a `t jump;b clean^J:jump^J` on posix version where `^J` is a real new line)